# Azure Custom Domain occasionally down

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, dns, web-hosting

So I have an Azure Asp.Net application. I also have a custom .gg domain name bought from Gandi. I've used custom domain names with Azure apps and Go Daddy before with no problem. I set the A, CNAME, and TXT records up the same way I've done in the past and mapped the records to the host on the Azure portal and it was successful the first day. My problem is, about 25% of the time when the user goes to the domain they see the default 'This page is owned by Gandi but their's nothing here'. This happens to different users and at different times of the day. The records were created over week ago so the DNS records should have fully propagated by now but their continue to be issues. I'm at a loss of why it only works MOST of the time.

Edit: Also, hard refreshing the page never fixes the issue, you just have to wait like 30 min till it's back up and the azure hosted domain is always up and working even when the custom .gg domain is down.

Comment: Can you transfer the domain to GoDaddy? I don't know anything about Gandi, but it sounds like they may be having issues with their DNS Servers. If you can't use GoDaddy, I highly recommend DNSimple.

Comment: See troubleshooting tip #4 for a possible explanation: [10 tips for troubleshooting DNS problems](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-for-troubleshooting-dns-problems/)

Comment: I would love to transfer it to GoDaddy but they don't do .gg domains. And that's a requirement from the guy I'm doing the website for :(. It defaults to their own nameservers tho, I'll try and switch to DNSimple and see if that helps. Thanks!